# ActivityRecognitionClient of activity Recognition cannot resolve ,error in android

Tags: android, performance, android-intent, android-activity, geolocation

I am trying to use `ActivityRecognition` in android to detect whether the user is driving or not.

http://www.kpbird.com/2013/07/android-activityrecognition-example.html: This is an example code I have been trying...

But when I write `ActivityRecognitionClient  client;`  my IDE(Android Studio) says it cannot resolve it, and marks it red, but `ActivityRecognition` is resolved.

So I manually imported `com.google.android.gms.location.ActivityRecognitionClient;`, but it was also marked as red, I have already installed all the google Api's and playservices,

Please help me to get through! :)

This is my Gradle.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion "Google Inc.:Google APIs:21"
buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "interrupt.smart.com.smartinterrupt"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])


compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:6.5.87'
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the [Google Play Services 6.5 highlights](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html):

> Deprecated clients - The `ActivityRecognitionClient`, `LocationClient`, and `PlusClient` classes are deprecated. If you used those APIs in your app and want to call Google Play services 6.5 or higher APIs, you must switch to the new programming model that utilizes [GoogleApiClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.html). For more information about using [GoogleApiClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.html), see [Accessing Google APIs](https://developer.android.com/google/auth/api-client.html).
>
> Use these APIs instead of the deprecated APIs:
>
> - If you were previously using `ActivityRecognitionClient`, call [ActivityRecognition](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/ActivityRecognition.html) instead.

Assuming you have a connected `GoogleApiClient`:

```
PendingResult<Status> result = ActivityRecognition.ActivityRecognitionApi
    .requestActivityUpdates(
        googleApiClient,         // your connected GoogleApiClient
        detectionIntervalMillis, // how often you want callbacks
        callbackIntent);         // the PendingIntent which will 
                                 //   receive updated activities

// Callback is asynchronous. Use await() on a background thread or listen for
// the ResultCallback
result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
    void onResult(Status status) {
        if (status.isSuccess()) {
            // Successfully registered
        } else if (status.hasResolution()) {
            // Google provides a way to fix the issue
            status.startResolutionForResult(
                activity,     // your current activity used to receive the result
                RESULT_CODE); // the result code you'll look for in your
                              // onActivityResult method to retry registering
        } else {
            // No recovery. Weep softly or inform the user.
            Log.e(TAG, "Registering failed: " + status.getStatusMessage());
        }
   }
});
```